# Primefaces gmap not rendered when style="display: none"

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

This is working:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="map-wrapper">
                <p:gmap center="#{locationService.getLatLngAsString(userSession.location)}"
                        zoom="15"
                        type="HYBRID"
                        model="#{addOfferController.emptyModel}"
                        onPointClick="handlePointClick(event);"
                        style="width:600px;height:400px"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

This is not:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="map-wrapper" style="display: none">
                <p:gmap center="#{locationService.getLatLngAsString(userSession.location)}"
                        zoom="15"
                        type="HYBRID"
                        model="#{addOfferController.emptyModel}"
                        onPointClick="handlePointClick(event);"
                        style="width:600px;height:400px"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

In the second code there is only  div with specified height and width inside map-wrapper.

What could be the reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that some PF components need dimension information to render themselves on client side. When they are in a container that has `display: none;`, problems often occur.

I've just found a workaround:

- Add a widgetVar property to your g:map component `widgetVar="gmap"`
- In the same page, add this javascript `<script type="text/javascript">gmap._render();</script>`